# How to constrain weights in TensorFlow from changing sign?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've seen several posts about adding simple constraints (i.e. non-negativity) to TensorFlow weight variables, but none about how to prevent a weight from changing signs. For example, if I have 
`W = tf.get_variable('W1', [512, 256], initializer=initializer, dtype=tf.float32)`
how do I add a constraint such that after initialization `W[i,j]` cannot change sign? I don't see a clear way to use the "constraint" option in tf.get_variable().

Comment: I am interested to know in what type of cases this could be a useful constraint.  It will help the community if you could also add that also in your questions.

Answer (score 1):

My approach to solve this problem will be as following.

For each weight, you store the initial sign. This can be done using the following code

```
w1 = tf.get_variable('W1', [512, 256], initializer=initializer, dtype=tf.float32)
w1_sign = tf.zeros_like(w1)
store_sign = tf.assign(w1_sign, tf.sign(w1))
```

You can use the following code to make the weights 0 whenever they break the sign constraints.

```
constraint_op = tf.assign(w1, tf.where(w1_sign * w1 >= 0, w1, 0))
```

Now you can run the above code as follows

```
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
sess.run(store_sign)
for _ in range(train_itr):
    sess.run(some_train_op)
    sess.run(constraint_op)
```

Note that in the above code, you are running the op `store_sign` only once and you are running the op `constraint_op` after each run of `train_op`.

The same idea can be applied with `constraints` argument of `tf.get_variable`.